# Finding number times a word appears in a textfile in C

Tags: c, file, io

I'm writing a program that takes a string from standard input, and reads a text file to see if there's a match in the text file. Everything works except if you add a space at the end of the text file, then the output is as follows...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
bool stringsEqual(char* str1, char * str2){
    if(strlen(str1)!= strlen(str2)){
        return false;
    }
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str1); i ++){
        if(str1[i] != str2[i]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void main(){
    char * readFileName = "read5.txt";
    FILE *reader = fopen(readFileName,"r");
    char * word;
    word = (char*) calloc(50,sizeof(char)); //word can be max 20 letters.
    printf("Please enter the word you are looking for: ");
    scanf("%s",word);
    char *line = "";
    line = (char*) calloc(150,sizeof(char));
    int count = 0;
    char c ;
    if(word){
        if(reader){
            while(!feof(reader)){
                fscanf(reader,"%s",line);
                printf("%s ----> %s\n",line,word);
                if(stringsEqual(line,word)){
                    count++;
                }  
                // strcpy(line,""); //Reset the value assigned to line
            }
            printf("Number of matches: %d\n",count);
        }

        else{
            printf("File cannot be located or does not exist\n");
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Your word cannot be processed\n");
    }
}
```

The Text file is as follows...

```
apple banana orange raspberry
```

and the output from the console is as follows

```
Please enter the word you are looking for: raspberry
apple ----> raspberry
banana ----> raspberry
orange ----> raspberry
raspberry ----> raspberry
raspberry ----> raspberry
Number of matches: 2
```

ADDITIONAL INFO:
- The line endings for both the text file and the text editor that the C program is written in are both LF.
- I tried to use fgets and fgetc, but fscanf is the best way to look at a text file and read it word by word.

Comment: Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) You can control the loop with the function value returned by `fscanf`. Such as `while(fscanf(reader, "%s", line) == 1)`

Comment: jorra04, who or what text suggested `while(!feof(reader)){`?

Comment: Why would you take the string from stdin?  Imagine if `grep` behaved like that!  `echo pattern-to-match | grep path`.  It becomes really difficult to stream text to your program.  Parameters are useful.  `argc` and `argv` are a *good* idea.  Use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fscanf returns on success the number of items of the argument list successfully filled.

So, you may want to check the return value of fscanf which should be 1 in your case.

If it is not 1, break the while-loop.